# Cards View Gray Color

Tags: android

My problem is that when i try to change the radius of the cardView i get this in the Image below:
any help would be appreciated.

These words just to  skip the error your post is mostly code:
skipping stupid error.

[image]

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cv"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardCornerRadius="10dp">
        <!--android:padding="16dp"-->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/team_photo"
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:layout_margin="8dp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/team1Linear"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/team1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="ssss"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="15sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/team1_score"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="end"
                        android:text="ssss"
                        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="15sp" />
                </LinearLayout>


                <View
                    android:id="@+id/separator"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:background="@color/background_material_light" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/team2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="ssss"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="15sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/team2_score"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="end"
                        android:text="ssss"
                        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="15sp" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Instead of `android:background="@color/white"` use `app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/white"` with CardViews. Not doing so will result in odd looks especially before Lollipop.

Comment: Tried it still the same!

Comment: What version of android do you use for testing? Is this inside a ListView or a RecyclerView or a LinearLayout? Have you tried RecyclerView instead?

Comment: lolipop and RecyclerView

Answer (score 1):

you need to use

```
app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
```

this will do that job for you

Answer (score 0):

Those are shadows of CardViews. It's normal, there is no problem.

So CardViews have their `elevations` that they drop shadows on the background.

You set radius for the CardViews. Then you can look the background through rounded corners. You see the shadows of CardViews dropping on the background.

```
app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
```

If you don't want the rounded corners of the CardViews, I think you should just set the radius to 0.

```
app:cardCornerRadius="0"
```

Comment: Do you mean that i should change the background of the recyclerView?

Comment: Before that, why do you set radius? Setting radius means making that rounded corners. If you don't want that, you should set radius to 0.

Comment: I need it but the shadow doesn't appear the right way.

Comment: How? I think on the white background dropping gray shadows in your picture is normal.

Answer (score 0):

add this, your problem with the shadow

```
app:cardElevation="@dimen/dp_0"
```